# Choosing a Python Code Editor/IDE for powering a webapp

Tags: python, ide, google-colaboratory

I use Colab for writing scripts, but need a code editor/IDE to power up a web app. Basically writing code, using the output file as an input for another app.  More of Colab-like frontend for a backend app. What's the best way to do this?

Usecase is similar to Hackerrank.

Comment: editor/IDEs don't "power up" a web app... are you just asking which editor you should use in general? That sort of question is off-topic for stack overflow

Comment: I meant designing an environment that has an editor and a compiler - where multiple users can login and run codes simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

My editor of choice is [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/). There are plenty others out there though. The free version works well for me.